# Changing mode from default to developer getting error

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.3

I have just change our magento2.3.3 mode from default mode to developer mode

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

I am getting ERROR how to resolve it anyone can you please help me.?

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'container', attribute 'cacheable': The attribute 'cacheable' is not allowed.
Line: 738

Element 'block', attribute 'type': The attribute 'type' is not allowed.
Line: 890

Element 'referenceContainer', attribute 'after': The attribute 'after' is not allowed.
Line: 938


Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'container', attribute 'cacheable': The attribute 'cacheable' is not allowed.
Line: 738

Element 'block', attribute 'type': The attribute 'type' is not allowed.
Line: 890

Element 'referenceContainer', attribute 'after': The attribute 'after' is not allowed.
Line: 938

<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct('<layout xmlns:xs...', &Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState#000000007ffc9088000000006ff6f5f3#, array(), NULL, '/srv/users/serve...', '%message%\nLine: ...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:116]
    </pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you have upgraded from a lower version to 2.3.3. Basically these are xml error, as these are not supported in your current magento version. You need to check your xml and change the attribute "type" from your xml files.

Example:-

```
<block type=""> to <block class="">
```

After that use these commands

1. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
2. php bin/magento cache:flush